# ORDER By CASE тормозит запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT TOP(@RecordCount) 
...
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [TransactionDateTime] END,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 1 THEN [TransactionDateTime] END DESC
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 2 THEN c.[Name] END,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 3 THEN c.[Name] END DESC
```

Он выполняется маскимально долго, ибо независимо от @RecordCount, обходит ВСЕ записи таблицы.
Стоит мне убрать CASE в ORDER BY - запрос выполняется почти моментально.
Как обойти это, сохранив возможность гибкой сортировки? Я вижу пока единственный вариант - формировать текст запроса динамически, с жестко заданной сортировкой. Сейчас это - хранимая процедура.
Но неужели нет других способов? Сейчас вся бизнес-логика прописана в хранимых процедурах, не хотелось бы от этого отступать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Запрос не приводит к ошибкам

Comment: Вы плохо смотрели - тут мнжественный CASE используемый на самом деле как IF

Answer (score 1):

Можно собрать запрос таким образом. Тогда в самом запросе не будет лишних вычислений.

```
DECLARE @OrderBy INTEGER
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @ORDERING VARCHAR(255)
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT 1 [TransactionDateTime], ''a'' [Name] UNION ALL SELECT 2 [TransactionDateTime], ''b'' [Name]'

SET @OrderBy = 1

IF (@OrderBy = 0) SET @ORDERING = ' ORDER BY [TransactionDateTime] ASC'
ELSE IF (@OrderBy = 1) SET @ORDERING = ' ORDER BY [TransactionDateTime] DESC'
ELSE IF(@OrderBy = 2)  SET @ORDERING = ' ORDER BY [Name] ASC'
ELSE SET @ORDERING = ' ORDER BY [Name] DESC'
    
SET @QUERY = @QUERY + @ORDERING
EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Comment: Там длиннющий запрос на 300 с лишним строк. Так что - не вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: не вижу проблемы. Можно использовать до VARCHAR(8000) , если строка до 8000 байт или VARCHAR(MAX), если текста до 2ГБ.

Comment: Да, вы правы, это лучшее решение. Я никогда раньше это не использовал, поскольку думал, что переносы строк нельзя использовать в строковой переменной :) Спасибо!

Comment: @stoi если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение